# How to iterate through nested array/hash and retrieve data from there

Tags: ruby

I stacked with a problem - solving a task where I have .yml file like this:

```
time:
  -
    begin: :washington
    end: :briston
    min: 6
    price: 3
  -
    begin: :briston
    end: :dallas
    min: 4
    price: 2
  -
    begin: :dallas
    end: :tokyo
    min: 3.5
    price: 3
  -
    begin: :tokyo
    end: :chicago
    min: 3.5
    price: 3
```

and a class Train, where I want to loop through this .yml file and extract neccessary information and operate with these values(start station, end station, price and duration).

```
class Train 
  require 'yaml'

  def initialize(time, line)
    @time = YAML.load_file(time)
    @line = YAML.load_file(line)
  end

  def calc(begin, end)
    @time.select do |key, value|
      puts key, value
    end
  end
end
```

In 'calc' method I defined 'select' method to retrieve keys and values, but it just printing all hash like this:

```
time
{"begin"=>:washington, "end"=>:briston, "min"=>6, "price"=>3}
{"begin"=>:briston, "end"=>:dallas, "min"=>4, "price"=>2}
{"begin"=>:dallas, "end"=>:tokyo, "min"=>3.5, "price"=>3}
```

How could I loop through this hash to extact neccessary data? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which data and how to retrieve? How to match arguments `begin`, `end` for selecting the required data? Chaining `end` with `begin`? Suggestion don't use reserved words as variable name: `begin`, `end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get the point, see my comment, given the variable `@time`:

```
@time = {"time"=>[{"begin"=>:washington, "end"=>:briston, "min"=>6, "price"=>3}, {"begin"=>:briston, "end"=>:dallas, "min"=>4, "price"=>2}, {"begin"=>:dallas, "end"=>:tokyo, "min"=>3.5, "price"=>3}, {"begin"=>:tokyo, "end"=>:chicago, "min"=>3.5, "price"=>3}]}
```

One way to chain, to be refactored:

```
ary = @time['time']
start = :washington
stop = :tokyo
res = []
loop do
  tmp = ary.find { |h| h['begin'] == start }
  break unless tmp
  res << tmp
  start = tmp['end']
  break if start == stop
end
```

Then you have `res`:

```
#=> [{"begin"=>:washington, "end"=>:briston, "min"=>6, "price"=>3}, {"begin"=>:briston, "end"=>:dallas, "min"=>4, "price"=>2}, {"begin"=>:dallas, "end"=>:tokyo, "min"=>3.5, "price"=>3}]
```

To get for example the sum of `min`:

```
res.sum { |h| h['min'] } #=> 13.5
```

Comment: Yes, dude)) Thank you a lot :)

Comment: Hey dude) I stucked at this point: tmp = ary.find { |h| h['begin'] == start } - this code breaks down with error `in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)`. Could you help me convert this to array type or with way to fix it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Add `p start` right after `loop do` to print out the value of the variable. Then post it here with the value of `ary`.

Comment: Actually i fixed some issue, but now my code starting without error and without necessary results a = Train.new("my_path_to yml", "my_path.yml) a.calc(begin: ':washington', end: ':dallas') p print - ":washington" first value of .yml file :washington.

Comment: It breaks on this line "break unless tmp" and that is all

Comment: It's strange, but I changed loop method:       for i in arry
      if i['start'] == 'washington'
        puts "good"
      else
        puts "no way"
      end
    end  And it all time prints "else" condition. I'm already sick of this code